# Turn off mirroring programmatically in iOS while airplaying to apple tv?

Tags: ios, xcode, airplay

I am working around airplaying in iOS and I can able to do that without any issues. My issue is when mirroring is turned on i can see my mobile screen on apple tv, but I want to turn off mirroring programmatically and have to show apple tv default player and this is possible because I seen Netflix app they are doing this.

So could any one help in this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive` property to YES.
Go through the following doc

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1624255-usesexternalplaybackwhileexterna